# If $(U,〈\;⋅\;,\;⋅\;〉),H$ are Hilbert spaces, $W\in U$, $Y\in H$, $Z\in L(U, H)$ and $f\in L(H,L(H,\mathbb R))$, then $〈Y,fZW〉=〈ZW,fY〉$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let

- $(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces
- $W\in U$, $Y\in H$ and $Z\in\mathfrak L(U, H)$$^1$
- $f\in\mathfrak L\left(H,\mathfrak L\left(H,\mathbb R\right)\right)$

> How can we show that $$\langle Y,fZW\rangle=\langle ZW,fY\rangle\;?$$

---

Let $\mathfrak L(A,B)$ be the space of bounded and linear operators from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Please apologize that I didn't show any effort to solve the problem. I've got a much more complicated problem in mind which I've broken down to this equation.

Comment: Strictly speaking the problem as stated makes no sense, since on the right you're taking the inner product of an element of $H$ and a linear functional on $H$. I suppose we can interpret this using the fact that $H=H^*$...

Comment: Then when I try that I get stuck on something else. Please rewrite the question so it makes sense and say exactly what you mean.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've exactly meant that what you've mentioned. $fx$ should be interpreted as being an element of $H$, for any $x\in H$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Maybe it helps you when you take a look at the [original problem](https://books.google.de/books?id=bxkmAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22To+find+the+limit+of%22+%2B+%22let+us+remark+that%22&source=bl&ots=-3enQaWN7v&sig=Ld9S8d3XDpoSRt-ZnvxU0ZlW2QQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYo9yB4KfMAhXDd5oKHWgRBVYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22To%20find%20the%20limit%20of%22%20%2B%20%22let%20us%20remark%20that%22&f=false). The relevant part is the third term of $I_3$. It seems like they've used the desired equation. The role of $(Y,Z,W)$ is played by $(\varphi_0,\Phi_0,\Delta W_j)$ there.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It's my fault. In the original problem, $f$ is the derivative of a Fréchet differentiable function at some point from $H$. Thus, by Schwarz' lemma, $f$ is symmetric and the claim obviously follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems false. Take $U=H$, $Z=Id$, and identify $L(H,\mathbb{R})$ with $H$. Take and orthogonal base $e_1,e_2\ldots,$ and define $f(e_1)=e_2$, $f(e_i)=0$ for $i>1$, extend by linearity. Then
$$
\langle e_2,f(e_1)\rangle=1\neq0\langle e_1,f(e_2)\rangle.
$$

Comment: It seems like you're right. Maybe you can take a look at the [original problem](https://books.google.de/books?id=bxkmAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22To+find+the+limit+of%22+%2B+%22let+us+remark+that%22&source=bl&ots=-3enQaWN7v&sig=Ld9S8d3XDpoSRt-ZnvxU0ZlW2QQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYo9yB4KfMAhXDd5oKHWgRBVYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22To%20find%20the%20limit%20of%22%20%2B%20%22let%20us%20remark%20that%22&f=false). The relevant part is the third term of $I_3$. It seems like they've used the desired equation. The role of $(Y,Z,W)$ is played by $(\varphi_0,\Phi_0,\Delta W_j)$ there.

Comment: It's my fault. In the original problem, $f$ is the derivative of a Fréchet differentiable function at some point from $H$. Thus, by Schwarz' lemma, $f$ is symmetric and the claim obviously follows.